# Precalc factoring

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

> Factor $$x(x+3)^{-\frac{3}{5}} + (x+3)^{\frac{2}{5}}$$

The solution is given as $$(2x+3)(x+3)^{-\frac{3}{5}}$$

I am not sure how to get this solution with the presence of a fraction as a power in the question statement, looking for some help!

Comment: When you want to factor out anything, you want to find some similar factor that is common to each thing you're adding. In this case, you can visually spot that both things you're adding have $(x+3)^a$ for some $a$. You know by the laws of powers that $x^{a+b}=x^{a}x^{b}$ so this gives you the tools to find the second equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $(x+3)^{-\frac{3}{5}}$ as a common term. Then you get:

$$(x+3)^{-\frac{3}{5}}(x+(x+3))=(x+3)^{-\frac{3}{5}}(2x+3)$$

It's because $\frac{(x+3)^{\frac{2}{5}}}{(x+3)^{-\frac{3}{5}}}=(x+3)^{\frac{3}{5}+\frac{2}{5}}=(x+3)$

Comment: again this makes sense, thanks a lot!

Comment: why is that term common?

Answer (score 1):

$$x(x+3)^{-3/5} + (x+3)^{2/5}=x\color{blue}{(x+3)^{-3/5}}+(x+3)\color{blue}{(x+3)^{-3/5}}$$

$$=(x+x+3)\color{blue}{(x+3)^{-3/5}}=(2x+3)\color{blue}{(x+3)^{-3/5}}$$